# .Net Core MVC - How to submit an MVC form to an actionMethod with Route attribute which includes params

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to submit a form to a `ActionMethod` with custom route which includes parameters.

```
[Route("Prop/{location}/{category}/{p}")]
public IActionResult Search(string location, string category, int p, string q)
{
    var vm = new ReloadVm();
    // rest of the code 
    return View(vm);
}
```

If I use `Html.BeginForm` than I get a `404` as it will try to load `https://localhost:44326/prop/search` and not the custom route. Previously I have used `window.location.href`, but I have been told it does not sit well with Google as well as now Chrome cancels the url requests by this `Javascript` call so it does not seem to be stable.

What is the best way to handle this?

Also, this action method has around 15 parameters and to keep the `url` clean, I would like to pass back only the parameters which are not null or 0, so I would end up with a `url` like `/Prop/London/Job/1?q=whatever&tt=222`.

Update - `window.location.href` works, the "trigger" button had to by defined as `type=button` otherwise it will cancel the `JS` request and treat it as a submit.

Still looking for a better way of doing this without `JS`

Comment: Give controller and action name in BeginForm with your parameters.

Comment: You could also use `type="submit"` with `event.PreventDefault()` on the form submit event or button click event.

Comment: Can you show your view code? the one with `Html.BeginForm` because I don't see how you set the action of the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Html.BeginForm() with custom routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308420/using-html-beginform-with-custom-routes)

Comment: You can use like this ` @using (Html.BeginForm("xxx", "Prop", FormMethod.Post,
            new { location= @Model.location,FormMethod.Post, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        { `,but it cannot only pass not null parameter to url,it will pass all parmeters you set in BeginForm

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your controller name is `PropController`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Prop", new
{
    location = "somewhere",
    category = "something",
    p = 1
}))
{
    <input name="q"/>
}
```

---

Make the parameters optional.

```cs
[Route("Prop/{location}/{category}/{p}")]
public IActionResult Search(string location, string category, int p, string q = null)
{
    var vm = new ReloadVm();
    // rest of the code 
    return View(vm);
}
```

OR use model binding

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string q { get; set; }
}
[Route("Prop/{location}/{category}/{p}")]
public IActionResult Search(string location, string category, int p, MyModel m)
{
    var q = m?.q;
    var vm = new ReloadVm();
    // rest of the code 
    return View(vm);
}
```